# Log4J for each context

Tags: java, xml, log4j2

currently I'm using Log4J2 on WebApps, which run on Tomcat. Each webapp has to push its logs to an individual folder, named like the webapp's context.

In the webapp I implemented an ServletContextListener, which get's noticed when the Webapp Context is ready. It sets the logging path to the system property like this:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    context = sce.getServletContext().getContextPath();
    if(context == null || context.isEmpty()){
        context = "ROOT";
    }
    System.setProperty("WebappContext", context);
    log.info("Context \"" + context + "\" erstellt");
}
```

Then I use this property in log4j2.xml:

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">/srv/tomcat/logs/${sys:WebappContext}</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="rollingLogFile" fileName="${log-path}/out.log"
                 filePattern="${log-path}/out-%d{MMM-dd--HH-mm}.log" >
     ...
    </RollingFile>
```

This works fine when I deploy the first webapp. But as soon as I deploy two or more, all logs from all contexts go to the newest folder, because the system property is global for all instances. Sometimes I even get a folder named "{sys:WebappContext}", where some logs are written.

What is the right way to achieve the loggin that I want?

Comment: If you still have issues with your logging you can refer to [Separate Log4j 2 instances for each web apps in Tomcat 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75233001/separate-log4j-2-instances-for-each-web-apps-in-tomcat-9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the web context lookup instead of system lookup.

Source:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#WebLookup

> The WebLookup allows applications to retrieve variables that are
>   associated with the ServletContext. In addition to being able to
>   retrieve various fields in the ServletContext, WebLookup supports
>   looking up values stored as attributes or configured as initialization
>   parameters. The following table lists various keys that can be
>   retrieved:

- attr.name    Returns the ServletContext attribute with
  the specified name
- contextPath  The context path of the web
  application
- effectiveMajorVersion    Gets the major version of the
  Servlet specification that the application represented by this
  ServletContext is based on.
- effectiveMinorVersion    Gets the minor
  version of the Servlet specification that the application represented
  by this ServletContext is based on.
- initParam.name   Returns the
  ServletContext initialization parameter with the specified name
- majorVersion Returns the major version of the Servlet API that this
  servlet container supports.
- minorVersion Returns the minor version of
  the Servlet API that this servlet container supports.
- rootDir  Returns
  the result of calling getRealPath with a value of "/".
- serverInfo   Returns the name and version of the servlet container on
  which the servlet is running.
- servletContextName   Returns the name of
  the web application as defined in the display-name element of the
  deployment descriptor

Example

```
<Appenders>
  <File name="ApplicationLog" fileName="${web:rootDir}/app.log"/>
</Appenders>
```

Comment: 'contextPath' did the job, thanks! For future readers: make sure you also have dependency log4j-web (version 2.5 or higher)!

Answer (score 2):

I typically just use a separate log4j2.xml for each web app with

```
<properties>
    <property name="LOG_DIR">${sys:catalina.home}/logs/AppName</property>
</properties>
```

However, if you want a single log4j2.xml, following alan7678's advice you should be able to add

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>applicationName</param-name>
    <param-value>AccountService</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to web.xml and then use

```
<properties>
    <property name="LOG_DIR">${sys:catalina.home}/logs/${web:applicationName}</property>
</properties>
```

However, I haven't tried this myself.