# Separate Log4j 2 instances for each web apps in Tomcat 9

Tags: java, log4j2, tomcat9

I am using Log4j 2 as logging framework in my application and running it on Tomcat 9.0.54. Now, if I deploy 2 instances of same application, it creates Log4j instance for first and all logs goes to the first application's log files.

For example, `Tomcat/webapps` has 2 folders i.e. 
APP1 
APP2

Both have logs folder under it, but logs are being created only in APP1/logs and logs for both applications are being updated there.

I tried configuring it from Java.

```java
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", Class.forName("com.example.MyAppListener").getResource("/log4j2.xml").toString());
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
if(!context.isInitialized()) {
    context.initialize();
}else {
    context.reconfigure();
}
```

I tried debugging Log4j 2 source, it appears to be that when context being initialized, it takes same configuration location for both applications. It seems like ClassLoader is loading single context object at Tomcat server level.

And web.xml as well

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The behavior is the same in both

Also, Log4j 2 jars are separately deployed in WEB-INF/lib folder for each application.

Comment: Can you add your `log4j2.xml` file to your question?

Comment: Are you sure there is no log4j2 library in the lib folder of Tomcat itself? That would take precedence over classes included in the WAR.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Tomcat's classloader uses a "parent last" delegation strategy. Log4j2 libraries in Tomcat's `lib` folder are invisible if the application embeds their own versions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: No, tomcat has no log4j library. It is using java.util.logging for its logging purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was the `configLocation`. When I tried to get the context, `configLocation` property was set null and log4j loaded the same configuration object when initializing the context which was used for the first application logger's context and its `configuration` property has `configLocation` of the first application. I modified my code to explicitly provide `configLocation` to the context object and it worked.

```
URL configLocation = Class.forName("com.example.MyAppListener").getResource("/log4j2.xml");
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
context.setConfigLocation(configLocation.toURI());
if(!context.isInitialized()) {
    context.initialize();
}else {
    context.reconfigure();
}
```

Comment: Yes, using system properties (which are global to the JVM) is never a good idea, but the approach using `/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml` should work out of the box (it's the default location used by [`log4j-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-web)). You either don't have `log4j-web` or don't have a file in `/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml` of your WAR file.

Comment: That was just an extra code setting system property, I removed that line.