# Get host context Parameter from tomcat server.xml to log4j2

Tags: tomcat, log4j2

I want to get host context parameter from Tomcat server.xml and insert it into my log4j2.xml file to create separate directory for each war that I run.

ex.

server.xml

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

<Context path="/App1" docBase="/opt/xx/deployments/App1.war" distributable="true">
            <Parameter name="applicationName" value="app1" />
</Context>

<Context path="/App2" docBase="/opt/xx/deployments/App2.war" distributable="true">
            <Parameter name="applicationName" value="app2" />
</Context>
</Host>
```

and when I run tomcat receive separate path

./logs/app1/app1.log

./logs/app2/app1.log

I tried to use

```
    <Property name="applicationName">$${jndi:applicationName</Property>
```

and then put it into
fileName  ${sys:applicationName}/${sys:applicationName}.log

but I received in catalina.out

WARN Infinite loop in property interpolation of applicationName->jndi:applicationName

Answer (score 1):

The [`<Parameter>`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters) element does not define a JNDI environment, but a servlet context parameter (cf. [`ServletContext#getInitParameter`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletcontext#getInitParameter-java.lang.String-)).

To retrieve those you need to use the [Web Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#web-lookup) available in the [`log4j-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-web) (or [`log4j-jakarta-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-jakarta-web)) artifacts:

```
${web:initParam.applicationName}
```

If you don't want to define the application names manually, you can:

- use `${web:contextPathName}` that will give you "" for the root context, "foo" for the application at `/foo` and "bar" for the application at `/bar/baz`,
- use the small Tomcat-specific lookup I wrote (cf. [Github](https://github.com/copernik-eu/log4j-plugins)):

  ```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>eu.copernik</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-tomcat</artifactId>
      <version>2.18.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

  and use:

  ```
  ${tomcat:classloader.webappName}
  ```

  This gives you the context path encoded according to [Tomcat's rules](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming): "ROOT" for the root context, "foo" for `/foo` and "bar#baz" for `/bar/baz`. It also works with application versioning.

**Remark:** The properties defined in the configuration file are default values for missing lookup values so if you define:

```xml
<Property name="foobar" value="${baz:foobar}"/>
```

you'll get a **recursive** definition if the `bar` lookup does not have a "foobar" value.

Answer (score -1):

This is different your approach but I believe below question will give insight to you.
[Another question: log4j-for-each-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481884/log4j-for-each-context)

From an answer of these question, referred this link [log4j reference(WebHook)](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#WebLookup) and provided sample config of appenders as below.

```xml
<Appenders>
  <File name="ApplicationLog" fileName="${web:rootDir}/app.log"/>
</Appenders>
```